# NSNotificationCenter is not sending out notifications

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotificationcenter

I am developing a system to keep track of achievements and for that I use `NSNotificationCenter`. When an achievement is unlocked in a object in the app a notification is sent to `JMAchievementHandler` which sets a string to `YES` and saves the progress in `NSUserDefaults`. My problem is that the notifications are not working probably. Here is my code in `JMAchievementHandler`:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        //Set strings to NO
        achievementOne = @"NO";
        achievementTwo = @"NO";
        achievementThree = @"NO";
        achievementFour = @"NO";

        //Add observers
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotificationWithName:) name:@"achievement1" object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotificationWithName) name:@"achievement2" object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotificationWithName) name:@"achievement3" object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotificationWithName) name:@"achievement4" object:nil];

        //Add observer to observe delegate methods
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotificationFromDelegate:) name:@"notificationLaunch" object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotificationFromDelegate:) name:@"notificationEnterBackground" object:nil];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)receiveNotificationWithName:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"achievement1"] || [achievementOne isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {

        //unlock achievement
        NSLog(@"%@ is unlocked", [notification name]);
        achievementOne = @"YES";
    }

    else if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"achievement2"] || [achievementTwo isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {

        //unlock achievement
        NSLog(@"%@ is unlocked", [notification name]);
        achievementTwo = @"YES";
    }

    else if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"achievement3"] || [achievementThree isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {

        //unlock achievement
        NSLog(@"%@ is unlocked", [notification name]);
        achievementThree = @"YES";
    }

    else if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"achievement4"] || [achievementFour isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {

        //unlock achievement
        NSLog(@"%@ is unlocked", [notification name]);
        achievementFour = @"YES";
    }
}

- (void)receiveNotificationFromDelegate:(NSNotification *)notificationDelegate
{
    if ([[notificationDelegate name] isEqualToString:@"notificationLaunch"]) {

        [self loadDataOnLaunch];
    }
    else if ([[notificationDelegate name] isEqualToString:@"notificationEnterBackground"]) {
        [self saveDataOnExit];
    }
}

- (void)loadDataOnLaunch
{
    NSLog(@"loadDataOnLaunch");
}

- (void)saveDataOnExit
{
    NSLog(@"saveDataOnExit");
}
```

When I try to post a notification the NSLogs are not called. I use the following code to send notifications from my `AppDelegate` and `ViewController`.

```
- (void)achievement1ButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"achievement1" object:self userInfo:nil];
}
```

I hope you guys can help me out. Thanks a lot

- Jonas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you even have a method named `receiveNotificationWithName`?  When you entered the code, the autocomplete should have barfed on that, offering `receiveNotificationWithName:` instead (unless you wrote it first, without `NSNotification*`, then added it later...

Anyway, there is a big difference between the two.  Also, your handler is buggy.  You should revisit that code.

There are lots of reasons to prefer blocks, and this points to one of them.  You can just put your code right in the registration, and not worry about giving the wrong selector.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"achievement1"
                                                  object:nil
                                                   queue:nil
                                              usingBlock:^{
    // Handle achievement1 right in this little block.
}];
```

These look like one-shot notifications, so if you want to unregister the notification handler after it runs one time, do this (note the `__block`).

```
__block id achievement1 = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                              addObserverForName:@"achievement1 ":^{
                                          object:nil
                                           queue:nil
                                      usingBlock:^{
    // Handle achievement1 right in this little block.

    // Remove observer from notification center
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:achievement1];
}];
```

Comment: FYI, this solution does work, but it will generate a retain on any objects accessed inside the inner block. http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/Dec/msg00096.html has much more information as to why. (Short answer: the `__block id` notification is retained, which copies the inner block. Without `achievement = nil` after `removeObserver:`, Obj-C doesn't know that the variable is done being used.)

Answer (score 1):

All of this looks like it should work (besides the colon, like Andrea mentioned).  Is it possible that your button callback isn't being called for a similar reason?  I would add an `NSLog` in your `achievement1ButtonPressed:` method to make sure.

Comment: Jody Hagins, thanks for the advice on using blocks it sure is a lot cleaner and more reliable. I will adapt the blocks pattern as soon as i return to my mac and i will try to put an NSLog insidenthe achievement1ButtonPressed method. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is that only one of your `addObesrver` method call the right selector with the ":", thus the right method signature.

Comment: That's not the solution to the main problem though, because the one that does have the colon still isn't being fired.

Comment: I have tried everything you told me and nothing works. I've placed a NSLog in the button methods and there are no problems concerning the buttons not to be hooked up probably to my controller.

Comment: Are you sure that the action of the button is called? Are you sure you are adding the observer before you can press the buttons and post the notification?

Comment: Ahh that is probably the problem! The observers are not added before the user can press the buttons. But how do i do that? I have them in a seperat class. How can i add the observers on launch?

Comment: Well, i suppose that the ibaction is declared in a view controller, and the observer is an object that shoul be used inside that class, I suggest you to create that object inside the viewDidload method of the view controller.

Comment: Andrea, thanks but when you say create should i then initialize the JMAchievementHandler class in my viewController?